# Comparing Maven project dependencies

Tags: maven

Is there a simple way to list the differences between the artefacts added to the classpath by one version of a Maven project and another?

Here is the problem I'm trying to solve. If I change the version of an artefact declared in a Maven project, the list of transitive dependencies added to the classpath by the dependency may change. I want know what those changes are before I commit a change to a dependency version. The primary reason I want to know what transitive dependencies will change on the classpath when I change the version number of declared dependency is concern that changing the version number of a declared dependency may cause the version of a transitive dependency to change to one that has a security vulnerability in it.

At the moment, I'm using the dependencies plugin tree goal to produce a before and after change dependency tree and then comparing the two by eye. This is not ideal.

I also know of a way to achieve my goal using the OWASP dependency check Maven plugin but this also seem not ideal.

Can anyone suggest a better solution to my problem that using the dependencies plugin or the OWASP dependency check plugin? Is there a Maven plugin to produce what I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try 
`mvn dependency:list`
It will list all the dependencies with version information.
now you can see the difference using any diff checker tool online.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The list goal appears to allow me to easily see the changes to the classpath when I use the list goal with the sort parameter. I'll experiment with this solution now. Cheers.